# Is it possible to create a bookmark in google chrome that takes the current url and adds something to it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url, bookmarks

I'm working with online databases from work and sometimes I need to edit the url by adding xmlonly=Y& right after the first ? in the url to see the xml data of the page for troubleshooting.

Is it possible to have a bookmark in the bookmark bar that when clicking it, automatically adds that string to the url of the website I'm on at the time of clicking?

I've tried to search for it on google and on here but not found anything that helped me or that I understood enough to make it work for me

I want it to change a URL, for example :

```
www.example.com/detail/detail?vid=2&sid=60dee09c-0207-4b62-862c-32d6394eda0b
```

to

```
www.example.com/detail/detail?xmlonly=Y&vid=2&sid=60dee09c-0207-4b62-862c-32d6394eda0b
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. It's called a "bookmarklet" - a bookmark that actually just executes JS code. You can manipulate the URL as normal with that.

Comment: why not create two bookmarks with and without xmlonly parameter?

Answer (score 1):

From
`www.example.com/detail/detail?vid=2&sid=60dee09c-0207-4b62-862c-32d6394eda0b`

to

`www.example.com/detail/detail?xmlonly=Y&vid=2&sid=60dee09c-0207-4b62-862c-32d6394eda0b`

using

[URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

```js
var sParms = new URLSearchParams("vid=2&sid=60dee09c-0207-4b62-862c-32d6394eda0b")
sParms.set("xmlonly","Y")

console.log(sParms.toString())
```

Bookmarklet (You can remove whitespace if you want)

```
javascript:(function() { 
  let sParms = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  sParms.set("xmlonly","Y"); 
  location.replace(
     location.protocol + '//' + 
     location.host + 
     location.pathname + '?' + 
     sParms.toString()
  ) 
})()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that sorted it