# How to create a Chrome shortcut that prepends the current URL with another?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, shortcut

I wanted to create a shortcut on Chrome that will add a string to the front of the URL of the current page, and load this new page on the same window, for example:

I am currently at https://stackoverflow.com/ and when I press the shortcut, it will replace the URL with https://test.shortcut/https://stackoverflow.com/ and go to that new URL on the same window

Comment: Persio, what have you tried?  Do you have any sample code you're debugging?

Comment: Do you mean a bookmarklet?

Comment: @ITgoldman yes, a bookmarklet

Comment: @Lucretius I'm not a coding expert much, but from researching here on SO I found some similar endeavors (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56850608/is-it-possible-to-create-a-bookmark-in-google-chrome-that-takes-the-current-url) but it changes stuff in the middle of the URL. I haven't been able to adapt it since I know zero JS

Comment: @ITgoldman it totally worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just make this into a bookmarklet, with the obvious modifications:

```html
<a href='javascript:window.location="https://www.google.com/search?q="+encodeURIComponent(window.location)'>drag me to bookmarks bar</a>
```